# SpringBoot test isolation not guaranteed

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

I created a SpringBoot test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-dev.properties")
@Transactional
public class ContactTests2 {
    private Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private ContactRepository customerRepository;

    @Autowired
    private StoreRepository storeRepository;

    @Autowired
    private NoteService noteService;

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    private Store store;

    @Before
    @WithMockUser(roles = "ADMIN")
    public void setup() {
        log.debug("Stores {}", storeRepository.count());
        store = createStore();
        storeRepository.save(store);
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = "ADMIN")
    public void saveWithNote() {
        Contact customer = new Contact();
        customer.setPersonType(PersonType.NATURAL_PERSON);
        customer.setFirstName("Daniele");
        customer.setLastName("Rossi");
        customer.setGender(Gender.MALE);
        customer.setBillingCountry(Locale.ITALY.getCountry());
        customer.setShippingCountry(Locale.ITALY.getCountry());
        customer.setStore(store);

        Note note = new Note();
        note.setGenre(NoteGenre.GENERIC);
        note.setOperationType(AuditType.NOTE);
        note.setText("note");

        customer = customerRepository.save(customer);

        noteService.addNote(note, customer);
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = "ADMIN")
    public void save() {
        Contact customer = new Contact();
        customer.setPersonType(PersonType.NATURAL_PERSON);
        customer.setFirstName("Daniele");
        customer.setLastName("Rossi");
        customer.setGender(Gender.MALE);
        customer.setBillingCountry(Locale.ITALY.getCountry());
        customer.setShippingCountry(Locale.ITALY.getCountry());
        customer.setStore(store);

        customerRepository.save(customer);

        assertEquals(customer, customerRepository.findById(customer.getId()).get());
    }

    // ====================================================
    //
    // UTILITY METHODS
    //
    // ====================================================

    private Store createStore() {
        Store store = new Store();
        store.setName("Padova");
        store.setCode("PD");
        store.setCountry("IT");
        return store;
    }
}
```

this is the note service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
public class NoteService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private NoteRepository noteRepository;

    /**
     * Add a note to a specific object (parent).
     * 
     * @param note
     * @param parent
     * @return the added note
     */
    public Note addNote(Note note, Persistable<Long> parent) {
        // ****************************************************
        // VALIDATION CHECKS
        // ****************************************************
        Assert.notNull(note, InternalException.class, ExceptionCode.INTERNAL_ERROR);
        Assert.notNull(parent, InternalException.class, ExceptionCode.INTERNAL_ERROR);
        // ****************************************************
        // END VALIDATION CHECKS
        // ****************************************************

        note.setParentId(parent.getId());
        note.setParentType(parent.getClass().getSimpleName());
        note.setRemoteAddress(NetworkUtils.getRemoteIpFromCurrentContext());

        note = noteRepository.save(note);

        return note;
    }
}
```

I'm using Hibernate and Mysql 5.7. The problem is that the test called `saveWithNote()`. When I run this test, following tests fails because the `setup()` method throw a duplicated exception. It seems the previous test is not rolledback.

This is what happens:

[image]

Removing the line `noteService.addNote(note, customer);` everything works like a charm.

What am I doing wrong? Why test isolation is not preserved?

Comment: have you tried to add `@DirtiesContext`?

Comment: @dehasi that solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using a real data store as the dependency.
When running saveWithNote(), the customer entry is persisted in database. It is not removed in your test setup, so the when you run save(), you bump into a duplicate database entry.

**Solution 1:**
Use teardown() method to remove database entries you created during the test.
Example:

```
    @After
    @WithMockUser(roles = "ADMIN")
    public void teardown() {
        // delete the customer entry here
    }
```

Reference: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/junit/junit-setup-teardown-example/

**Solution 2:** Every time you run setup(), wipe the database tables clean.
Example:

```
    @Before
    @WithMockUser(roles = "ADMIN")
    public void setup() {
        // wipe your database tables to make them empty
    }
```

Both solution 1 and 2 should be done with test database only. You **DON'T** want to clean up production DB.

**Solution 3 (recommended):**
Use mocked repositories and mock injection (instead of autowiring repositories with real implementation).

Sample/ Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36004293/5849844

Comment: Thanks for your reply, even if using mocked up repositories is a good practice, I don't think that's the problem. In fact if I remove the line  noteService.addNote(note, customer), each test is rolled-back as it should be (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tx).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your table is using [MyISAM storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) which does not support transactions (as per *Table 15.2 MyISAM Storage Engine Features* docs).

Redefine the table using [InnoDB storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-storage-engine.html). Take a look at [14.8.1.1 Creating InnoDB Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-innodb-tables.html) docs, it should be on by default but you can check it with:

```
SELECT @@default_storage_engine;
```

Comment: Actually I'm using InnoDB